# Spring MVC - PDF content is not displayed

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, pdf

I've pretty basic setup of Spring MVC and want to add a static PDF resource so that users can download it.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ApiConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addRedirectViewController("/more", "/resources/special_services_appendix.pdf");
        }

        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) { 
            registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/");
        }
}
```

When I try to access the URL it is resolved properly, however the PDF document is blank and not content is displayed. I checked the response and the content type, length are correct so nothing suspicious. The PDF itself looks fine, I can open it without any error and see the content.

Is there anything I miss regards static resources?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your code and it should serve the PDF file. Infact I did a quick test using your code on Spring Boot 1.4.0 and I can see pdf file on browser. You should try with different browsers. Chrome has builtin pdf plugin. Try disabling that. On the blank screen do inspect element. Also check the Adobe Acrobat reader preferences setting. Hope this helps.